# How to move checkout progress block to right?

Tags: magento, block, checkout, progress

In magento , i want to move checkout progress block from right to left. I mean i want to show the checkout page as 2columns-right style.I have an extension at left side column which i don't need in checkout page.
so, how can i manage it ?
I have tried in checkout.xml by changing the reference name to right, but it won't work.
**Here is my xml code**

```
<!--
One page checkout main layout
-->

    <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout</label>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">

             <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.progress.wrapper" translate="label">
<label>Checkout Progress Wrapper</label>
<action method="setElementId"><value>checkout-progress-wrapper</value></action>
<block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="checkout.progress" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
<block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="billing.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"></block>
<block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shipping.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml"></block>
<block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shippingmethod.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml"></block>
<block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="payment.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/payment.phtml"></block>
</block>
</block> 


        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage" name="checkout.onepage" template="checkout/onepage.phtml">
                <block type="checkout/onepage_login" name="checkout.onepage.login" as="login" template="checkout/onepage/login.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.onepage.login.before" as="login_before">
                        <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.billing" as="billing" template="checkout/onepage/billing.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping" name="checkout.onepage.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method" as="shipping_method" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml">
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available" as="available" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.additional" as="additional" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_payment" name="checkout.onepage.payment" as="payment" template="checkout/onepage/payment.phtml">
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
                        <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_review" name="checkout.onepage.review" as="review" template="checkout/onepage/review.phtml">
                    <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>

<!--
One page checkout progress block
-->

    <checkout_onepage_progress>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_info" name="payment_info">
                <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress>

<!--
One page checkout payment methods block
-->
    <checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
            <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>


<!--
One page checkout shipping methods block
-->

    <checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
    </checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>

    <checkout_onepage_additional>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml">
            <action method="setDontDisplayContainer"><param>1</param></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_additional>

<!--
One page checkout order review block
-->

    <checkout_onepage_review>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
        <block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.review.button" as="button" template="checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml"/> 
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before"/>
            <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
```

Please help

Comment: Why dont you show some of your code as its literally impossible to help you without seeing what you are working with

Comment: Ok..i shared ....tnx@AndyHolmes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--Remove everything from left-->
<remove name="left"/>
<!--Change root template to 2columns-right.phtml-->
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<!--use the right block-->
<reference name="right">

    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.progress.wrapper" translate="label">
        <label>Checkout Progress Wrapper</label>
        <action method="setElementId"><value>checkout-progress-wrapper</value></action>
        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="checkout.progress" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="billing.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"></block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shipping.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml"></block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shippingmethod.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml"></block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="payment.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/payment.phtml"></block>
        </block>
    </block> 
</reference>
<reference name="content"....
```

hope it will help you !

Comment: Dima , Is the changes only for main layout ?